# Exporting query from MS Access to CSV, columns with lengthy text with linebreaks get cuts off

Tags: vba, ms-access, export-to-csv

I have a MS Access file and it has a form with a button which export a named query to a CSV file. When i open the CSV to Excel, a column with lengthy text with line breaks get cuts off. When i tried to copy and then paste special as CSV on the Excel it turns out to be fine.

[image: Exported from my vba code as CSV file]

[image: Manually pasting it to excel as paste special as CSV]

Here is my VBA code

```
Public Sub exportQuery(exportSQL As String)
Dim db As DAO.Database, qd As DAO.QueryDef
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

Set db = CurrentDb
'Check to see if querydef exists
For i = 0 To (db.QueryDefs.Count - 1)
    If db.QueryDefs(i).Name = "tmpExport" Then
        db.QueryDefs.Delete ("tmpExport")
        Exit For
End If
Next i
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("tmpExport", exportSQL)

'Set intial filename
fd.InitialFileName = "export_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyy") & ".csv"

If fd.Show = True Then
    If Format(fd.SelectedItems(1)) <> vbNullString Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tmpExport", fd.SelectedItems(1), False
    End If
End If

'Cleanup
db.QueryDefs.Delete "tmpExport"
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set qd = Nothing
Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

And this for command button to call the function

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim queryStr As String
'Store Query Here:
queryStr = "SELECT [Name],[Notes] FROM [GetListForUpload]"
Call exportQuery(queryStr)
End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Tested your code and no cut off. Must be something about your data.

Comment: @June7 i dont think so. But why is that pasting manually the lengthy texts to excel as paste special CSV works fine but cant work from exported csv?

Comment: I have no idea. Since I cannot replicate issue, cannot determine cause.

Comment: I haven't used Access in years, which is why I read your post with interest and I stumbled over `acExportDelim`. This enumeration appears to instruct to use a delimiter set in the Regional Settings. Perhaps this would be a comma. But what is supposed to happen when there is no comma within 256 characters? If that is what you are finding out you might solve your problem by setting another delimiter in your Regional Settings, perhaps LF or CR.

Comment: @Variatus thanks for the heads up sir. Will try that and give you feedback

Comment: @Variatus sorry, but where is this regional settings?

Comment: It should be in the Control Panel, where you also set defaults for date, time and number formats, list separators and the like.

Comment: @Variatus can't seem to find adding another delimiter

Comment: I did a little more research on this and found that it's the `List Separator` which also works as the default for imported CSV data. BTW, you might change it using code, just for the occasion. Along the way I fund this thread. I can't make head or tail of it but they seem to have found a solution (not involving the list separator). https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=44469

Comment: Got this. Thanks @Variatus will check on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem haha! So i just want to share this for any other who stumbled from this situation. Their's this hidden system objects that you want to show up in navigation options. So first is you check to show the hidden system objects in the navigation options and you will see tables that is greyed out ex.(MSysIMEXColumns, MSysIMEXSpecs) then create a specification. Open the table MSysIMEXColumns, you will see all of the field names on the specification you've created. So on my part i have Notes column which contains lenghty texts with linebreaks. In the MsysIMEXColumns table, I changed the DataType for the fieldname Notes from 10 (Text) to 12 (Memo) and voila. No lenghty texts get cuts off or truncated anymore :)

PS: If you have more than 1 specifications created please identify the specid first from MSysIMEXSpecs and then check it in MSysIMEXColumns before you changed anything for not to get confused.